# Concern on trust.p12 and key.p12 from websphere application server

Tags: websphere

i can see the trust.p12 and key.p12 exist both under path $PROFILE_HOME/etc and $PROFILE_HOME/config/cells/cellname/

so what's the difference between files under these two path?

and i can see the websphere default ssl setting referring to trust.p12 and key.p12 under $PROFILE_HOME/config/cells/cellname, is there any other configuration referring to file under $PROFILE_HOME/etc?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

trust.p12 is the Trust Store: the other sites' certificates that you trust. key.p12 is the Key Store: your own SSL certificates.

Answer (score 0):

These key stores (/etc) are used by clients (for example, wsadmin) started from this profile